# How to go through 2 lists and do a check

Tags: java, javafx

I have this list that will save the id of all my selected checkboxes according to my table in the ex database: my table parts in the database has the following fields id / name / qtdPecas

```
List<Pecas> pecasList = new ArrayList<>();
    {
        if (checkMonitor.isSelected()) {
            Pecas p = new Pecas();
            p.setIdpecas(1);
            pecasList.add(p);
        }
        if (checkTeclado.isSelected()) {
            Pecas p = new Pecas();
            p.setIdpecas(2);
            pecasList.add(p);
        }
        if (checkMouse.isSelected()) {
            Pecas p = new Pecas();
            p.setIdpecas(3);
            pecasList.add(p);
        }
        if (checkVGA.isSelected()) {
            Pecas p = new Pecas();
            p.setIdpecas(4);
            pecasList.add(p);
        }
        if (checkPlacaMae.isSelected()) {
            Pecas p = new Pecas();
            p.setIdpecas(5);
            pecasList.add(p);
        }
        if (checkHD.isSelected()) {
            Pecas p = new Pecas();
            p.setIdpecas(6);
            pecasList.add(p);
        }
        if (checkFonte.isSelected()) {
            Pecas p = new Pecas();
            p.setIdpecas(7);
            pecasList.add(p);
        }
        if (checkRam.isSelected()) {
            Pecas p = new Pecas();
            p.setIdpecas(8);
            pecasList.add(p);
        }
        if (checkCabos.isSelected()) {
            Pecas p = new Pecas();
            p.setIdpecas(9);
            pecasList.add(p);
        }
        if (checkGravador.isSelected()) {
            Pecas p = new Pecas();
            p.setIdpecas(10);
            pecasList.add(p);
        }
        if (checkBateria.isSelected()) {
            Pecas p = new Pecas();
            p.setIdpecas(11);
            pecasList.add(p);
        }
    }
```

and I have a list to check if you have stock of this item in the database

```
public List<Pecas> pegarPecas() {
    List<Pecas> pecaslist = new ArrayList<>();
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM  pecas";
    try {
        PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {       
            Pecas pecas = new Pecas();
            pecas.setIdpecas(rs.getInt("id_pecas"));
            pecas.setNome(rs.getString("nome"));
            pecas.setQtd_Pecas(rs.getInt("qtdPecas"));
            pecaslist.add(pecas);
        }
        stmt.close();
        rs.close();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(RequisicaoDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        return null;
    }

    return pecaslist;
}
```

I wanted to go through these two list to do a check pick up the id of the check box that the user select compare with id of the database and pick up the available amount I tried to do with this:

```
  List<Pecas> pecasList2 = new ArrayList<>();{
    for (Pecas pecasVerificacao : pecasList) {
                pecasVerificacao.getIdpecas();
            for (Pecas pecasBanco : pecasDAO.pegarPecas()) {
            if(pecasBanco.getIdpecas() == pecasVerificacao.getIdpecas()){
                pecasVerificacao.setQtd_Pecas(pecasBanco.getQtd_Pecas());
                pecasVerificacao.getIdpecas();
                pecasList2.add(pecasVerificacao);
            }
    }
    } 
    }
```

I do not know if I did it the best way

however I can get the required data for each selected item
id
and quantity

now i can not do an if
for if the quantity of each item in the list is> 0 call my method

all this is to check if you have a quantity of parts in the database greater than 0
I did not imagine another way to do
I'm new with java
If anyone helps me, I'll be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not optimal.

```
for (Pecas pecasVerificacao : pecasList) {
    for (Pecas pecasBanco : pecasDAO.pegarPecas()) {
         ...
    }
}
```

This executes the query once for every element in `pecasList`. In general you want to keep the communication to the DB/amount of data transferred to a minimum. Retrieving all the elements multiple times is unnecessary. A simple fix without much need to rewrite would be to simply retrieve the results only a single time and reuse them:

```
final List<Pecas> pecas = pecasDAO.pegarPecas();
for (Pecas pecasVerificacao : pecasList) {
    for (Pecas pecasBanco : pecas) {
         ...
    }
}
```

However this retrieves more data than you actually need. The `IN` operator could be used to retrieve only the values you're interested in. Furthermore your first code snippet contains much boilerplate code. Store your `CheckBox`es in a list to avoid this issue:

```
private CheckBox[] checkBoxes;
```

Make sure the following code is executed once after creating the `CheckBox`es.

```
checkBoxes = new CheckBox[] {
    checkMonitor,
    checkTeclado,
    checkMouse,
    checkVGA,
    checkPlacaMae,
    checkHD,
    checkFonte,
    checkRam,
    checkCabos,
    checkGravador,
    checkBateria
};
```

(You may want to use a different data structure to store the data, if you cannot guarantee the index range is 1, ..., n).

This way you can rewrite the code filling `pecasList` as follows (I'm simply storing the ids here):

```
List<Integer> pecasList = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < checkBoxes.length; i++) {
    if (checkBoxes[i].isSelected()) {
        pecasList.add(i+1);
    }
}
```

```
public List<Pecas> pegarPecasById(List<Integer> ids) {
    if (ids.isEmpty()) {
        return new ArrayList<>(0);
    } else {
        String sql = ids.stream().map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(",", "SELECT * FROM pecas WHERE id_pecas IN (", ")"));

        try {
            PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {       
                Pecas pecas = new Pecas();
                pecas.setIdpecas(rs.getInt("id_pecas"));
                pecas.setNome(rs.getString("nome"));
                pecas.setQtd_Pecas(rs.getInt("qtdPecas"));
                pecaslist.add(pecas);
            }
            stmt.close();
            rs.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(RequisicaoDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            return null;
        }

        return pecaslist;
    }
}
```

This way you get the only the results for checked boxes. This should make the nested loop unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've got a question regarding the checkbox I need to checkBoxes = new CheckBox [] on initialize?

Comment: I could not understand this part very well:
(You may want to use a different data structure to store the data, if you can not guarantee the index range is 1, ..., n).

Comment: If your logic is in a fxml controller then `initialize` is indeed the appropriate method. Storing the `CheckBox`es in a array this way only works, if all the ids are consecutive, i.e. the ids 1, 2, 3, ..., n are all there; you may need to use a `Map<CheckBox, Integer>` or `List<Pair<CheckBox, Pecas>>` allowing you retrieve the combination of `CheckBox` and the corresponding entry in the db.

Comment: for (Pecas checarQtd : pecas.pegarPecasById(pecasList)){
            if(checarQtd.getQtd_Pecas()>0){
                alerts.alertReqCadastrado();
            }else{
                alerts.alertSenhaDif();
            }
        }

Comment: if I have an id with an amount greater than one of the alert
and if I have an id equal to 0 of the other alert
could you help me how to fix this if?

Comment: because if i have 10 checkbox select and 8 dont have quanty > 0 program go got 8 alerts.